# Uploading a file with WebdriverIO and Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I'm doing some simple automation scripts using WDIO and Cucumber. I'm using test website for "uploading a file" example. I was looking for some solutions but no help was satisfactory.

I tried to follow these steps:

- https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/uploadFile.html
- https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/06/25/file-upload.html

My final "When" step looks like:

```
When('I pick example file from path', () => {
    const input = Upload.fileUpload
    const submitBtn = Upload.fileSubmit
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/file_path_on_desktop/');
    const remoteFilePath = browser.uploadFile(filePath);
    input.setValue(remoteFilePath);
    submitBtn.click()
});
```

And I have received error

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path_to_project_folder/file_path_on_desktop/'
```

which is weird.

Maybe I just did smth wrong due to Cucumber, or it's just not supported with Cucumber? However I tried without it and I also had same issue.

Error shown at this line
`const remoteFilePath = browser.uploadFile(filePath);`

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution.
Maybe I missed it somewhere, but in that case, `__dirname` shouldn't be here.
Or move the file from desktop to repository folder, then `__dirname` may stay as it is.